# codeUnits property vs utf8.encode function in Dart

Tags: dart, utf-8, utf-16

I have this little code:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  const data = 'amigo+/=:chesu';
  var encoded = base64Encode(utf8.encode(data));
  var encoded2 = base64Encode(data.codeUnits);
  var decoded = utf8.decode(base64Decode(encoded));
  var decoded2 = utf8.decode(base64Decode(encoded2));

  print(encoded);
  print(encoded2);
  print(decoded);
  print(decoded2);
}
```

The output is:

```
YW1pZ28rLz06Y2hlc3U=
YW1pZ28rLz06Y2hlc3U=
amigo+/=:chesu
amigo+/=:chesu
```

`codeUnits` property gives an unmodifiable list of the UTF-16 code units, is it OK to use `utf8.decode` function? or what function should be used for `encoded2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply not a good idea to do `base64Encode(data.codeUnits)` because `base64Encode` encodes *bytes*, and `data.codeUnits` isn't necessarily bytes.
Here they are (because all the characters of the string have code points below 256, they are even ASCII.)

Using `ut8.encode` before `base64Encode` is good. It works for all strings.

The best way to convert *from* UTF-16 code units to a `String` is [`String.fromCharCodes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCodes.html).

Here you are using `base64Encode(data.codeUnits)` which only works if the `data` string contains only code units up to 255. So, if you *assume* that, then it means that decoding that can be done using either `latin1.decode` or `String.fromCharCodes`.
Using `ascii.decode` and `utf8.decode` also works if the string only contains ASCII (which it does here, but which isn't guaranteed by `base64Encode` succeeding).

In short, don't do `base64Encode(data.codeUnits)`. Convert the string to *bytes* before doing `base64Encode`, then use the reverse conversion to convert bytes back to strings.

Comment: According your explanation, `codeUnits` goes with ASCII chars, however its definition `An unmodifiable list of the UTF-16 code units of this string` is a little misleading for me. But you are right, I tried `codeUnits` with this string `中国新闻，养僵尸` and I got an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
  print(utf8.decode('use âsmartâ symbols like â thisâ'.codeUnits));
```

and got this

```
use “smart” symbols like ‘ this’
```

The ” and ‘ are smart characters from iOS keyboard